# Google-drive is not downloading all the folders and all the files in each folder

Tags: google-drive

I have formatted my hard drive C recently, while formatting only Drive C, mistakenly all the drives were merged i.e I lost all the saved data.

I downloaded my data from google drive but for some reason, many folders have not been downloaded and many files in many downloaded folders have not been downloaded. Many folders having names starting from 'a' to 'i' have been downloaded but none after 'i' downloaded.

I have tried file recovery programs as well but in vain. I have lost most of my very important data. Could anyone help me download remaining data from google drive. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your Google Drive content online to make sure that the data you seek is still there.

If it is, then it's really just a matter of time that they get downloaded to your PC. Just force a synchronisation if you believe that the Drive app stopped working, or restart your computer.

If the files are not on Google Drive anymore, then all that is left is to try to recover them from your PC disk. There are many good tools around that will support you in that endeavour and if the data is really vital to you, you could consider sending the disk in to a professional data recovery service.

Answer (score 0):

First are the file in google drive?

https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive

1. If so click the first file/folder and then shift-click the last folder.
2. Right click **download**
3. Wait for the ZIP file to be completed, and download it.
4. Unzip as you see fit on your PC.

If not there, click on the trash can and see if the files exist are there.

Repeat the same procedure above for downloading.

Else

You need a second hard drive(a drive with no files that need recovering) with enough space.  Download testdisk from cgsecurity and save it to the second hard drive.  Run it as administrator, let it scan your whole drive for hours and a recup_dir will appear.  Then something like recup_dir.1 through whatever recup_dir.500.

It may not 100% everything, and some of the filenames will be scrambled but you should still be able to recover a significant number of files.  Other recovery products cost money.